# Different sheet references in an "OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH))) array for a Vlookup

Tags: match, vlookup, offset, excel-indirect

I have two worksheets, called "Holdings" (main one) and "Prove" (second one).

I am currently experiencing an issue with a Vlookup with a variable array.

I have a variable data set, which can freely expand rows-wise, but keeps a standard layout columns-wise.

In order to tell the vlookup which values to fetch from the table, I wrote down their list, next to the vlookup formula.

I am able to fetch the correct values if I apply the formula in the main sheet, but when I type it in the second one, adding "Holdings!" before references, it turns out #N/D.

Can someone please help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble reading the formulas in Italian, can you translate them for me? Have you tried simply cop-pasting the formula from the first sheet to the second? Also, why is this an array formula? It looks as though its gathering a single point of data, does it need to be an array?

Comment: "Cerca.Vert" is "Vlookup"

Comment: "Cerca.Vert" is "Vlookup", "Scarto" is "Offset", "Indirizzo" is "Address", "Confronta" is "Match", "Indiretto" is "Indirect". For the thing I am currently working on, I needed to define more dynamic arrays in the same columns, therefore I could not use a named dynamic range. Since the names in bold in column B are the only anchors in the changing database, the offset/match function defines the dynamic array starting from them (starting point is 3 rows, 3 columns down from "Cash", ending point is -1 row, 5 columns from "Equity").